# What is the Policy for Updating grub-pc in LTS?

Tags: grub2, stable-release-updates, policy

After having attempted an [SRU request for a small patch to grub-pc](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/563895) for 10.04 LTS that fixes an issue that has left many people with unbootable servers nothing has been done for some time.  The patch went through d-i into Maverick and only modifies a small amount of a single *.c file over a year ago.  I updated the ticket with a debdiff of the patch and rebuilt the current grub-pc package plus the patch in a PPA and changed the ticket description to be the SRU request format subscribed the "sru" and "sponsors" teams but then nothing happened.

Is there some policy against updating grub-pc in LTS that I don't know about?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you ask this question in the wrong place... I guess best would be to use IRC.

Comment: I guess you were wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a question of time, not policy.  Sorry for not having dealt with this yet.  I've opened a bug target in an effort not to forget again.

Comment: Thank you for this insight.  I would like to say that you are very much appreciated!  May you be happy and well.